# Passing JSON from server-side (.NET) to client-side (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, .net

I'm trying to load in JSON from the URL below :

https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001090170/timeline?gameHash=a23ccbe7928a63a3

My code looks like this :

```
   var baseUrl = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001440043/timeline?gameHash=4725b07311676885";
   var json = $.getJSON(baseUrl, function(data){
    });
    $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(json));
```

And my output reads this :

```
{"readyState":1}
```

Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lwjpjmo/

**EDIT** : Apparently it is not possible to retrieve the JSON from that URL because of 2 reasons:

1. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null`
2. JSON is called via Proxy Requeste to load the JSON in the body.

I already can retrieve the JSON server-side via .NET but need to pass on certain variables to the client-side to manipulate in jQuery. How do I go about this?

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate... JSONP is different..

Comment: @BasvanStein There's no JSONP here. What made you think there's a JSONP?

Comment: @PraveenKumar because it does work with `callback`.. it just gives malformed json though, so there is another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do so difficult, the server does accept `JSONP`. Just add the `callback=?` parameter to your url and it works fine.

```
baseUrl = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001440043/timeline?gameHash=4725b07311676885&callback=?";
```

The "JSON" that you get back is malformed however

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. (anonymous function)timeline:1
```

### **EDIT**

It appears that the server does not return JSONP either, using a proxy service you can make it work:

```
var proxyUrl = 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/';
var serviceUrl = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001440043/timeline?gameHash=4725b07311676885";
var url = proxyUrl + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(serviceUrl) + '&callback=?';
```

Comment: I tried using the `JSONP` datatype earlier but to no avail. Updated fiddle with `&callback=?` parameter and still doesn't work.

Comment: That is true, your code does not work but the call does. Check the console.. let me give you correct code in a minute.

Comment: @BasvanStein Sure... Waiting. `:)`

Comment: That's strange. It seems to load here http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c40cabfeb194b26a813658f28e1707fe just fine. I've coded with this JSON in .NET but trying to accomplish the same feat in jQuery

Comment: Perhaps that one is more robust, at least in Safari Javascript it gives the parse error.

Comment: @TaylorM They use Proxy request / just get the JSON in their body.

Comment: @TaylorM I found out that there is an existing proxy service such that you do not need to make your own. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @TaylorM I gave the same solution, except which I didn't give out a proxy URL and spoonfeed you. Anyways. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

It is an asynchronous function. Moreover, you are receiving only the XHR object. So, put it inside the function:

```
var baseUrl = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001440043/timeline?gameHash=4725b07311676885";

$.getJSON(baseUrl, function(data) {
  json = JSON.parse(data);
  $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

This should work.

You need to use a **Server Side Script** like Proxy PHP file, that reads the content and executes it correctly.

`Proxy.php`:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    die(file_get_contents($_GET["url"]));
?>
```

And call it like this:

```
url: "proxy.php?url=https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001440043/timeline?gameHash=4725b07311676885"
```

Comment: @TaylorM **You can't.** See the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH3/1001440043/timeline?gameHash=4725b07311676885. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'null'. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` It doesn't allow AJAX requests to that URL.

Comment: **From the Server:** `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null`

Comment: Okay thank you. So there is no way to load in the html value from that page into jQuery?

Comment: @TaylorM You can use a proxy script. Lemme update the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar your answer is not so good.. the server accepts JSONP which is way more elegant than your hack.

Comment: @BasvanStein Oh... Great then I will delete my answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to accomplish the same feat (Server Side Script) using a Web Form in .NET?

Comment: @TaylorM Using ASP.NET you can use [`Request.InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx).

Comment: Okay. I don't mind accepting your answer to this question. But if theres any resources you can point me to to get a better handle and to help get this implemented? I already am able to retrieve the JSON correctly via Server Side but cannot access it Client Side. I need to retrieve certain variables to perform certain a task in jQuery.

Comment: @TaylorM I will definitely call out for you.

Comment: @TaylorM I have reopened the question for you. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the title and made an edit update to the question.

Comment: Added it back. Wasn't sure if it impacted if the question being unanswered or not in terms of getting more people to give their input

Comment: @TaylorM given the many problems with this json feed, your method probably works best in the end. +1

Comment: I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>();` to read in the JSON server-side. But how do I pass that variable string to jQuery after being initialized?

Comment: @TaylorM `Response.Write` or something? Then use getJSON.